# Why does selenium only get a part of the HTML from a webpage?

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I tried to use `selenium` to navigate the web-untis webpage and look for any tests taking place this week, but I can't find the web-elements in the html-file that contain the data for the lessons. All the other stuff like the menu is in the file, but the tree of the timetable is gone.

So far, I tried waiting longer to give the page time to load in, using different search patterns and trying to go up the tree. `Selenium` never found anything and always returned an empty `list`.

Here is the code I wrote so far(unoptimised prototype):

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

# setting webdriver up
url = "https://klio.webuntis.com"
path = "C:\Program Files (x86)/chromedriver.exe"
options = Options()
options.add_argument("headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(1.0)

###################################################################################################

# getting to login screen
schoolParent = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "Select-input")
schoolInput = schoolParent.find_elements(By.XPATH, "*")[0]
schoolInput.send_keys("<schoolName>")
time.sleep(0.6)
schoolInput.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(1.0)

# logging in
userInputs = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "un-input-group__input")
for element in userInputs:
    if element.get_attribute("type") == "text":
        element.send_keys("<username>")
    elif element.get_attribute("type") == "password":
        element.send_keys("<password>")
        element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(1.0)

# going to timetable
buttons = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "item-container")
time.sleep(0.5)
for element in buttons:
    if element.text == "Mein Stundenplan":
        element.click()
time.sleep(5)
thisWeek = bs(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
test = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "un-timetable__dnd-avatar un-timetable__dnd-avatar--hidden")
print(test)
# time.sleep(5.0)
# buttons = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[type=button]")
# for element in buttons:
#     print(element.get_attribute("class"))                                 come back later...
#     if element.get_attribute("class") == "btn btn-default":
#         print("should work...")
time.sleep(6.0)

####################################################################################################

# printing html-file
print(thisWeek.prettify())
```

btw, the class I am searching for actually exists when I inspect the element in chrome:
[image: sample Image]

Comment: Since it all happens behind a login, it is not easy to find out the exact reason, like looking into a crystal ball.

Is the element possibly located in an iframe?

Comment: Yes, it is located in an iframe if you mean these things at the start of a new line like this: <iframe>(Sorry for my missing knowledge, this is my first time working with html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the element is in an `<iframe>` you have to switch into this frame - You could use [`WebDriverWait`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html):

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"id_of_the_iframe")))
```

and use `css selector` or `xpath` to select by **multiple** classes:

```
driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'un-timetable__dnd-avatar.un-timetable__dnd-avatar--hidden')
```

##### Example

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.maximize_window()
url = 'https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe?retiredLocale=de'

driver.get(url)
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"frame_a_simple_iframe")))

print(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'h1').text)
# --> <iframe>: The Inline Frame element
```

or work on the `driver.page_source`:

```
print(driver.page_source)
```